# Speed of sound in a liquid mixture

Tags: acoustics, velocity

I need to compute the sound velocity of a mixture of different magmas and their gases.

Thanks to this site  I already found the way to compute the sound velocity of the gas, but what about the liquid part? It would be very kind of you to give me an hint on how to compute the sound speed of a liquid mixture.

Comment: It is the same...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Wilson and Roy *'An Audible Demonstration of the Speed of Sound in Bubbly Liquids'* 2008](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/31138/SpeedOfSoundBubblyLiquids.pdf?sequence=1). The authors provide several equations for the speed of sound, $c$.

I'm not sure what parameters you're looking to use to calculate $c$, but the authors give the following formula for low frequencies (*presumably low enough not to be scattered by the bubbles, themselves*):

$$c^{2}_{mlf} \simeq \sqrt{\frac{\nu \ P_{\infty}}{\rho_{\ell} \chi (1 - \chi)}}$$

Where $\nu$ is the [*polytropic index*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process), $P_{\infty}$ is the hydrostatic pressure, $\rho_{\ell}$ is the density of the liquid, and $\chi$ is the *void fraction*, given by:

$$\chi = \frac{V_g}{V_{total}}$$

The main premise of the paper, as the title suggests, was to create an apparatus to demonstrate the effect of bubbles on the speed of sound, but it also serves the rather elegant purpose of providing a test of the theory.

---

An alternative approach may be adopted from [Kieffer 1977 *'Sound Speed in Liquid-Gas Mixtures: Water-Air and Water-Steam'*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.6144&rep=rep1&type=pdf), given the following constraints:

> - there are two (or two predominant) components to the mixture
> - the liquid and gas phases are in equilibrium, and there is negligible mass transfer between the phases owing to gas becoming dissolved or liquefied
> - there is no slip between the liquid and gas phases
> - the wavelength of the sound wave is much larger than the average dimension of nonuniformity of the mixture
> - the gas is compressible and obeys the perfect gas law
> - the liquid is elastic with a constant bulk modulus

the speed of sound of the mixture is given by:

$$c = \eta \ \rho_{LA} \ (\frac{G_{gas}}{P})^{\frac{1}{\gamma}} + e^{\frac{P_a - P}{K}} \Biggr \lbrace [(1 + \eta) \ \rho_{LA}]^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \biggl [\frac{\eta \ \rho_{LA} \ {G_{gas}}^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}}{\gamma \ P^{\frac{(\gamma + 1)}{\gamma}}} + \frac{1}{K} \space \space e^{\frac{P_a - P}{K}} \biggr ]^{\frac{1}{2}} \Biggr \rbrace$$

where the pressure within the gas bubbles and the liquid are equal, $P_{gas} = P_{liquid} \equiv P$,

$P_a$ is the reference pressure (*1 bar*),

$\rho_{LA}$ is the density of the liquid phase in a reference state,

$\gamma$ is the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) (*i.e., isentropic exponent*),

$G_{gas} = \frac{T_0 R_0}{{M \rho_{0}}^{\gamma - 1}}$, given by molecular weight $M$, $T_0$ is a reference temperature (*100° C at 1 bar*), $R_0$ is the gas constant, and $\rho_0$ is the density of the gas in the reference state,

$\eta = \frac{M_G}{M_L}$ is the gas mass fraction, and

$K$ is the bulk modulus of the liquid.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the problem still remains because i have a mixture of 4 liquids (with gas bubbles). If I understood in the right way this formula is for one liquid with bubbles. Is there any way to extend it to more than one liquid?

Comment: Is your liquid a homogeneous  mixture?  If so, then you should be able to determine a single speed of sound for the liquid part of the magma.  If not, there will be some more complicated reflection and refraction effects and you may have to model your system as several interacting acoustical systems.

Comment: It is far from being an homogeneous mixture. It is composed of two different compositions of anhydrous magmas (andesite and dacite), dissolved water and dissolved carbon dioxide. It is a nightmare! Do you have any reference for "you may have to model your system as several interacting acoustical systems"? I searched and searched but found nothing for magmas. Is there a general formula? Or some quantities has to be measured in laboratory? Thank you very much for your kind attention.

Comment: @AntonellaLongo, take a look at [Kieffer 1977 Sound Speed in Liquid-Gas Mixtures: Water-Air and Water-Steam](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.6144&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  The author describes the relevance as applicable to _"numerous geologic situations"_.  At this point it's worthwhile to ask what frequencies you're interested in - depending on the wavelength of the sound as compared to the 'average dimension of non-uniformity' there may be some simplifying assumptions.